# killed jobs getting binded to the ports

Tags: netty, apache-storm

I am submitting a topology to the apache storm cluster and it throws me the following error. I am using storm version 1.0.1

> 2016-08-16 10:06:21.250 o.a.s.m.TransportFactory [INFO] Storm peer transport plugin:org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Context
>
> 2016-08-16 10:06:21.395 o.a.s.m.n.Server [INFO] Create Netty Server Netty-server-localhost-6704, buffer_size: 5242880, maxWorkers: 1
>   2016-08-16 10:06:21.411 o.a.s.d.worker [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker
>
> org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6704
>
> at    org.apache.storm.shade.org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>
> at org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Server.(Server.java:101) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>
> at org.apache.storm.messaging.netty.Context.bind(Context.java:67) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>
> at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$worker_data$fn__8152.invoke(worker.clj:271) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
>
> at org.apache.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:930) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]

Comment: Are you intending to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6704?

Comment: no. i am using distributed mode.

Comment: The problem is the previously killed jobs are not releasing the ports that they have used. And i assume nimbus is considering these ports as released.